# expand collapse using jquery for tree node not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am making tree with the help of jquery in the tree whenever there is more than one child for a particular child i want to gave a toggle effect.it means that there should be a plus icon on click of it tree should expand and minus image should come on click of minus tree should collapse and plus image should come.

how to develop this any working example of tree node will be helpful

In this manner i have used your function

```
function createSpanImageNode(spnNew) {
    var spnImage = document.createElement("span");
    spnImage.id = spnNew + "_" + "spn1";
    $(spnImage).addClass('SpanPlus');
    spnImage.setAttribute('onclick', 'toogleNode("' + spnImage.id + '")');
    return spnImage;
}

function toogleNode(spnID) {
        debugger;
        var dv = $("#" + spnID).parents("div:first");
        var chkUl = $(dv).find('ul').length;
        if (chkUl > 0) {
            if ($("#" + spnID).hasClass('SpanPlus'))
                $("#" + spnID).removeClass('SpanPlus').addClass('SpanMinus');
            else
                $("#" + spnID).removeClass('SpanMinus').addClass('SpanPlus');
            $(dv).find('ul').animate({ height: 'toggle' });
        }
    }
```

the two actions that it should perform are
1)remove the class with the span and add the class with minus.
2)it should toggle the ul.

both is not working????

Comment: Is it possible to use a plugin like this? http://jquery.bassistance.de/treeview/demo/

Comment: @matt i have done that can you tell me how to use the animate with toggle

Comment: @arnab  i cant use it since i have made my own control as per requirment

Comment: more code, please. where are these functions called from? sample html would also be nice.

Comment: you also have a misprint: `toogleNode` instead of `toggleNode`, but you repeat it twice, so it should not harm anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: //$(dv).find('ul').animate({ height: 'toggle', opacity: 'toggle' });
 instead of the above line i made a small change and it worked for me                                           $(dv).find('ul').toggle();

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.navbar .dropdown-item').on('click', function (e) {
    var $el = $(this).children('.dropdown-toggle');
    var $parent = $el.offsetParent(".dropdown-menu");
    $(this).parent("li").toggleClass('open');

if (!$parent.parent().hasClass('navbar-nav')) {
    if ($parent.hasClass('show')) {
        $parent.removeClass('show');
        $el.next().removeClass('show');
        $el.next().css({"top": -999, "left": -999});
    } else {
        $parent.parent().find('.show').removeClass('show');
        $parent.addClass('show');
        $el.next().addClass('show');
        $el.next().css({"top": $el[0].offsetTop, "left": $parent.outerWidth() - 4});
    }
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
}
});

$('.navbar .dropdown').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
    $(this).find('li.dropdown').removeClass('show open');
    $(this).find('ul.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show open');
});

});
```

for full menu you can find here

http://blog.adlivetech.com/how-to-make-vertical-menu-with-plus-minus-toggle/